# r: Integral of squared brownian bridge

Tags: r, simulation, integral

I am a new user in R, and currently struggling with a problem to simulate the critical values of the sum of integral on squared of Brownian bridge, shown as,

\sum_{l=1}^{\delta}\int_{0}^{1}B_l^2(t)dt

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx2VI.jpg)

The true Critical Values: [1.33, 1.84, 2.90] at 90%, 95% and 99% significance level.

But the process generated from my R code contains some errors, mainly because I am not sure how to take integral of brownian bridge in [0,1], the Vectorize function in R is not very clear for me, and not quite sure wehther the CDF I generated is right or not. My code is:

```
rm(list=ls())
reps<-2000 #the number of replications in simulation
nobs<-1000 #the sample size for each brownian bridge 
dim=2 #the dimensionality=2, so that \delta=3 in the above formula
delt=dim*(dim+1)/2
Bm<-matrix(0,nrow=reps,ncol=delt)

for(i in 1:reps){
   for (j in 1:delt){
   dt<-0.001
   T<-seq(0,1,dt)
   CB = rep(0, nobs); #The containter for cumulative squared brownian bridge
   B = rep(0, nobs);

   for (k in 1:length(T))
       {
        B<-B+BBridge(x=0, y=0, t0=0, T=1, N=nobs)    
        CB<-CB+(B*dt)^2
    }
   CB<-CB[!is.na(CB)]
   CBcdf = function(u) { return(mean(CB < u)) } # the CDF of squared brownian bridge
   st<-integrate(Vectorize(CBcdf), lower=0, upper=1,subdivisions = 2000)
   Bm[i,j]<-st$value
}
}
SimuB<-rowSums(Bm)
SimuB<-SimuB[!is.na(SimuB)]

cv90 <- quantile(SimuB, probs=c(90/100)) # critival values
cv95 <- quantile(SimuB, probs=c(95/100))
cv99 <- quantile(SimuB, probs=c(99/100))
}
```

This code generated wrong critical values...anyone can help? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the values it should return?

Comment: Hi Mark, thx for reply. The true value should be something around [1.33, 1.84, 2.90] under 90%, 95% and 99% significance level. But what this code returned is [2.85, 2.87, 2.89].

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/sde/html/BM.html

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Hi, that is a function to generate a Brownian Bridge from 'sde' package. Thx~

Comment: @BenBolker yes~ thanks!